# Probability of intersection of two absolute correlated normal random variables

Tags: probability-distributions

Let $(X_1,X_2)\sim \mathcal{N}_{2}(\boldsymbol{\mu},\mathrm{\Sigma})$, where $\boldsymbol{\mu} = (\mu_1,\mu_2)^{T}$ and $\mathrm{\Sigma}$ is an appropriate variance matrix. Then how to find $\mathbb{P}(|X_1|>c\cap |X_2|>c)$?

Comment: can't you just integrate the Gaussian over $x_1$ and $x_2$, both over the intervals $(-\infty,-c)$ and $(c,\infty)$?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker I think no.

Comment: you mean "no" like "this integral has no closed form" --- but that should not stop you from evaluating it numerically...

Comment: Is it correct to write $\mathbb{P}(|X_1|>c\cap |X_2|>c) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(|X_1|\leq c)-\mathbb{P}(|X_1|\leq c)  + \mathbb{P}(|X_1|\leq c\cap |X_2|\leq c) $?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this probability cannot be expressed in closed form even when the means of the $X_i$'s are $0$ and their variances are $1$. At least, Mathematica cannot do anything with this probability:

[image]

-- as opposed, say, to this:

[image]

Comment: you would need a closed form for the indefinite integral of $e^{-x^2}\,\text{erf}(a+x)$, which is not available for $a\neq 0$.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker : Yes, we can of course integrate once, but not twice.